# Segmentation fault in scanning long long int in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, long-long

I'm trying to write a simple program to calculate the number of common factors for two numbers.I am stuck with segmentation fault(core dumped) occurring while scanning the second number.I don't understand where is the fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
long long int first,second,t,k;
long long int i,count=0;
scanf("%lld",&first);
scanf("%lld",&second);
//storing the lowest of two numbers in t  
if(first<second){
    t=first;
}
else{
    t=second;
}
//initialising an array to be used as flags
int com[t];
for(i=0;i<t;i=i+1){
    com[i]=1;
}
for(i=0;i<t;i=i+1){
    if(com[i]==1){
        if(first%(i+1)==0&&second%(i+1)==0){
            count=count+1;
        }
        else{
            for(k=2;k*(i+1)-1<t;k=k+1){
                com[k*(i+1)-1]=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("%lld\n",count);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't where your error is ([case and point](http://ideone.com/XrgEvb)). The undefined behavior is elsewhere. Check the return value of `scanf` and it's kin, always!

Comment: What input are you providing? How did you confirm that the segmentation fault occurred in the scanning process and not after it?

Comment: I checked my code by putting printf statements throughout and confirmed that it does indeed stop at the second scanf statement.

Comment: @Vishal So a `printf` followed by an `fflush` after the second `scanf` did not print? Can you edit your code to show that? (We can't debug code we can't see. And you don't know that *this* code faulted in the `scanf`.)

Comment: @Vishal - printf statement don't confirm anything. If output is buffered (as stdout often is) you won't see any printout near the actual crash site.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the second scanf doesn't work if the number is more than 6 digits.
specifically you can try this
123456789
9876543

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the code you see here is all the code I'm working on, there is nothing else.

Comment: @Vishal Okay, so you don't know that it's the second `scanf` that's faulting in that code. And that's the only code you're working on. Thank you.

Comment: @StoryTeller You are right, I checked the return value of scanf and it is 1 for both the scanf statements, so the error is somewhere else. Thanks for pointing out. Can you tell me what do you mean by output is buffered?

Comment: This is a stack overflow, which occurs here `int com[t];` when you try to allocate far too much memory on the stack.

Comment: @Lundin Gotit, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Vishal - Buffered output means that what ever you print doesn't appear in the terminal right away. Instead it's stored in a buffer by the call. The way, IO operations (which are somewhat costly) can be reduced. When the buffer is full, the entire content is printed at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your input is a truly big number (*edit: you confirmed it in a comment*). The call stack is fairly limited in size, and declaring a huge variable length array can easily overflow it.

Replace `int com[t];` with the following:

```
int *com = malloc(sizeof *com * t);
```

And don't forget to free it, of course, when you are done.